# How can I remove a substring, given a start and end token, in python?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a sting that looks like:

```
u'\'\'\'Joseph Michael "Joe" Acaba\'\'\' (born May 17, 1967) is an [[Teacher|educator]], [[Hydrogeology|hydrogeologist]], and [[NASA]] [[astronaut]].<ref name="bio">{{Cite web|url=http://www.jsc.nasa.gov/Bios/htmlbios/acaba-jm.html|title=Astronaut Bio: Joseph Acaba|month=February | year=2006|publisher=[[NASA|National Aeronautics and Space Administration]]|author=NASA|accessdate=November 26, 2006}}</ref><ref name="bio2">{{Cite web|url=http://oeop.larc.nasa.gov/hep/hep-astronauts.html|title=NASA Hispanic Astronauts\n|publisher=National Aeronautics and Space Administration|author=NASA|accessdate=November 26, 2006}}</ref> In May 2004 he became the first person'
```

I want to remove all the test from `<ref` to `ref>` including the markers. I'm new to python an am not sure of the best way to do this.

Comment: @dm03514 seems like yes.

Comment: Yes, its wiki text. I'm trying to remove the references as I have them elsewhere and am looking to clean up the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, a regular expression would work just fine:

```
import re
ref = re.compile(u'<ref.*?ref>', re.DOTALL)

ref.sub(u'', yourtext)
```

Note the `re.DOTALL` qualilifier; you have newlines inside your `<ref>` sections, and we want to remove those too.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> tst=u'\'\'\'Joseph Michael "Joe" Acaba\'\'\' (born May 17, 1967) is an [[Teacher|educator]], [[Hydrogeology|hydrogeologist]], and [[NASA]] [[astronaut]].<ref name="bio">{{Cite web|url=http://www.jsc.nasa.gov/Bios/htmlbios/acaba-jm.html|title=Astronaut Bio: Joseph Acaba|month=February | year=2006|publisher=[[NASA|National Aeronautics and Space Administration]]|author=NASA|accessdate=November 26, 2006}}</ref><ref name="bio2">{{Cite web|url=http://oeop.larc.nasa.gov/hep/hep-astronauts.html|title=NASA Hispanic Astronauts\n|publisher=National Aeronautics and Space Administration|author=NASA|accessdate=November 26, 2006}}</ref> In May 2004 he became the first person'
>>> ref = re.compile(u'<ref.*?ref>', re.DOTALL)
>>> ref.sub(u'', tst)
u'\'\'\'Joseph Michael "Joe" Acaba\'\'\' (born May 17, 1967) is an [[Teacher|educator]], [[Hydrogeology|hydrogeologist]], and [[NASA]] [[astronaut]]. In May 2004 he became the first person'
```

Comment: ha, nice, i thought the opposite, grab everyone outside the ref and put it together, :) actually, i am not sure which is more efficient, but yours obviously looks better.

Comment: @InbarRose: Matching the stuff you want removed is usually easier than matching everything else.